# Python code keeps giving timeout error! iterators vs generators?

Tags: python, iterator, timeout, generator

What I want is to generate all possible permutations of a string and then check to see if any of the permutation is a palindrome if it is then I just break out of the loop and assign found to be true but the problem I am facing is that the code keeps giving timeout error! now since I am new to Python I just have a basic understanding of generators and iterators, and I would like someone to point out how I can use generators effectively to solve this timeout issue.

```
from itertools import permutations
string = raw_input()
for perm in permutations(string):
    if perm == perm[::-1]:
        found=True
        break
if found==True:
    print("YES")
else:
    print("NO")
```

Comment: A *"timeout error"* on what? For how large a `string` (and *does* it have any palindromic permutations)? Why not just `if found:`, or `print` before the `break` and use the `for: else:` construction?

Answer (score 2):

Generators/iterators are not the cause of this problem, where I assume "timeout" means that it takes too long (on Hacker Rank). The problem is the time taken to process the vast number of permutations that even a moderately short string can generate. You are looking at a factorial time complexity because that is the number of permutations that exist for a given string.

Here is another way to do it without generating any permutations. Instead this algorithm simply relies on the fact that a palindrome can be formed for a string only if the counts of each character comprising it are even, or there is at most 1 character with an odd count.

```
from collections import Counter

def can_form_palindrome(s):
    return [v%2 for v in Counter(s).values()].count(1) < 2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if can_form_palindrome(raw_input()):
        print("YES")
    else:
        print("NO")
```

Comment: BTW, this passes the Hacker Rank Game of Thrones - I problem without timeout.

Answer (score 1):

That's not a problem of generators or not. Your algorithm is not optimal. Trying every possible permutation is not the best way, to check if a given set of characters can build a palindrom. Your algorithm has a complexity of O(N!) which grows faster than any exponential complexity, and exponential complexity is already very poor. But theres an algorithm with O(N), going linear with the number of characters.